# Is QSPI pseudo-sram here to stay?

Tags: spi, cortex-m, iot, psram

Doing a new design for a industrial printer that was using an expensive SRAM part on an old Hitachi part. The new Cortex M processor has limited bus pins, and we're thinking of putting a QSPI RAM on it.  There aren't a lot of vendors right now for them (AP Memory and maybe 1-2 others).

I this kind of memory her to stay - has it caught on in IOT, cellular, or any other large volume customers that would justify its continuance?  Trying not to pick something that'll be gone in a few years.

https://www.apmemory.com/products/psram-iot-ram/

Thanks

Comment: For now scoop up a few years  demand from surplus like EBay https://www.ebay.ca/itm/373638301218?mkevt=1&mkcid=1&mkrid=706-53473-19255-0&campid=5338722076&customid=&toolid=10050  cheap

Answer (score 1):

I expect this to have a long life perhaps with speed & size revisions.

High speed, low power small package, serial interface are all great qualities.

Price and Avail, is another matter depends on your relative demand and leverage.